# Group-Object diffencies with or without code block

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

The code below produce 2 "identical" Hashtables, however on the one that was grouped using a code block I can't get items from the key.

```
$HashTableWithoutBlock = 
    Get-WmiObject Win32_Service | Group-Object State -AsHashTable
$HashTableWithBlock = 
    Get-WmiObject Win32_Service | Group-Object {$_.State} -AsHashTable

Write-Host "Search result for HashTable without using code block : " -NoNewline
if($HashTableWithoutBlock["Stopped"] -eq $null)
{
    Write-Host "Failed"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Success"
}

Write-Host "Search result for HashTable with code block : " -NoNewline
if($HashTableWithBlock["Stopped"] -eq $null)
{
    Write-Host "Failed"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Success"
}
```

Output :

```
Search result for HashTable without using code block : Success
Search result for HashTable with code block : Failed
```

What is the difference between the two Hashtables ?

How to get Items on second one that was grouped by code block ?

EDIT : More than a workaround, I'd like to know if it is possible to retrieve the Item I want with a table **lookup**, and if yes, how ?

Comment: I noticed that using a block, you can obviously Group by multiple properties, which then turns the HashTable key into an object. However with only one property, I'd assume that it would be a plain string and that my lookup should work..

Comment: In $HashTableWithBlock keys are wrapped in `PSObject`, so `Hashtable` fail to compare them properly.

Comment: @PetSerAl I see, but then how can you make a correct lookup ? Even if I create a PSObject with a property, I suspect that the comparison will compare the object references..

Comment: Can you not group by multiple properties without using a block? What are you actually _trying_ to do? Why must you work with a hash table?

Comment: I can only propose to recreate `Hashtable`: `$HashTableWithBlock.GetEnumerator()|%{$HashTableWithBlock=@{}}{$HashTableWithBlock.Add($_.Key,$_.Value)}`

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks, I already found that recreating it would ĥelp with the issue, I was interested if there was a "normal" way of retrieving items

Comment: @arco444 I don't know if it is possible to group by multiples properties without a block. And what I actually do is trying to understand this specific mechanism of powershell hashtables.

Comment: It is certainly possible. `Get-Help Group-Object`. Just add more properties to group by... FWIW in my experience there's not usually much of a case for using hashtables, much easier to work with objects

Comment: @arco444 Although it's interesting, It actually doesn't answer my question (which has been updated to be clearer). If you look at the sample code, I'm not trying to use multiple properties anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between two `Hashtable`s is that `$HashTableWithBlock` have its key wrapped in `PSObject`. Problem is that PowerShell normally unwrap `PSObject` before pass it to the method call, so even if you have right key, you still can not just pass it to indexer. To workaround this you can create helper C# method what would call indexer with right object. Another way is to use reflection:

```powershell
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
    public static class Helper {
        public static object IndexHashtableByPSObject(System.Collections.IDictionary table,object[] key) {
            return table[key[0]];
        }
    }
'@
$HashTableWithBlock = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service | Group-Object {$_.State} -AsHashTable
$Key=$HashTableWithBlock.Keys-eq'Stopped'
#Helper method
[Helper]::IndexHashtableByPSObject($HashTableWithBlock,$Key)
#Reflection
[Collections.IDictionary].InvokeMember('','GetProperty',$null,$HashTableWithBlock,$Key)
```

Comment: @PetSerAI thanks, seems interesting. I however fail to see why the call table[key[0]] is different. Is it because of .Net's implicit casts to IDictionary and Object ? Because else, this would work : `$HashTableWithBlock[($HashTableWithBlock.Keys -eq 'Stopped')[0]]`

Comment: @LukeMarlin PowerShell will unwrap result `PSObject` of this expression `($HashTableWithBlock.Keys -eq 'Stopped')[0]` and pass just string in indexer.

Comment: @PetSerAI Thank you for the insight. I hope there's not many other weird things in PS compared to C# .Net though !

Answer (score 3):

The other posters are correct that the problem is with the key being stored as a `PSObject` but there is a built-in solution for this: use the `-AsString` switch along with `-AsHashTable`. This will force the key to be stored as a string. You can take a look at the code [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/group-object.cs#L363)

I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6933) on GitHub for this bug.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround I found, which is really not great:

```
$HashTableWithBlock = 
    Get-WmiObject Win32_Service | ForEach-Object -Process {
        $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName _StateProp -NotePropertyValue $_.State -Force -Passthru
    } |
    Group-Object -Proerty _StateProp -AsHashTable
```

I mean I guess once you're doing `ForEach-Object` you almost might as well just build a hashtable yourself?

Do note that, interestingly, this will *not* work if you group on a ScriptProperty instead. I haven't figured out why.