# Unexpected Behavior with Group-Object with ScriptBlock

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use Group-Object to group a list of objects based on a custom computation. A very simplified example is the following:

```
$groupedProjects = 1..10 | %{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ErrorMessage = if ($_ % 2) { 'SomeError' } else { '' } 
    }
} | Group-Object -Property { if ($_.ErrorMessage) { 'Failed' } else { 'Successful' } } -AsHashTable

$successGroup = $groupedProjects['Successful'] 
# $successGroup is null here instead of a list with the integers.
```

The problem is that the groups are not keyed by the string but by something else instead - not sure I really understand the problem.

PS: Using a script block is shown in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-6) in this manner:

```
1..35 | Group-Object -Property {$_ % 2},{$_ % 3}
```

so I'd assume the idea is valid - using integers instead of strings also works as intended. If there's a better way to do the above I'm all ears though.

Comment: Interesting. There is a larger discussion about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190053/group-object-diffencies-with-or-without-code-block

Comment: You're using an implicit foreach in your group call with that scriptblock for a property... why?

Comment: You're also not passing any non-even numbers to your group call in the first place.  You lack an else block in `ErrorMessage=`

Comment: @TheIncorrigle The missing else for the ErrorMessage was too much simplified, I'll fix it. Not sure what you mean with implicit foreach in the group-object script block. I'm using the script block for the property because I need a custom group property - how would you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other posters are correct that the problem is with the key being stored as a `PSObject` but there is a build-in solution for this: use the `-AsString` switch along with `-AsHashTable`. This will force the key to be stored as a string.

I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6933) on GitHub for this bug.